# Load database dump into postgres database

Tags: database, macos, postgresql

I have a database dump about 270MB which I want to load into my local postgres database. I typed in the following command:

```
pg_dump databasename < dumpfile.sql
```

After which I get:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

--
-- Name: plpgsql; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner:
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION plpgsql; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner:
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';


--
-- Name: public; Type: ACL; Schema: -; Owner: starlord
--

REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM starlord;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO starlord;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO PUBLIC;


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

To verify if the dump was successful and to check the data I logged into the psql terminal using `psql` which opens the psql terminal.

If I type `\l` I get all the databases. I typed `\c databasename` to connect to the database and then `\dt` to check the tables. However it keeps showing me `No relations found`. The same steps work totally fine for other databases ( loading a dump, and then connecting and displaying tables). Moreover after loading the dump if I type `\l+` to see the size of each database, the database I am interested in shows a size of `6973kb` where as the dump is `272MB`.

Any suggestions as to what could be the issue?

Comment: To clarify, did you try to load the database with `pg_dump databasename < dumpfile.sql`? If so, that's your problem. [`pg_dump`](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/master/pages/common/pg_dump.md) is for dumping, not loading.

Comment: Your redirection looks to be backwards - you're piping data *into* `pg_dump`, which is a tool for getting data *out* of the database. If you already have an SQL-format backup, you need to pipe it into `psql`, to actually execute the commands in the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`pg_dump`](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/master/pages/common/pg_dump.md) is for dumping the database. `pg_dump databasename < dumpfile.sql` will probably ignore the input file and spew the dump to the screen, which seems to be what you got.

To restore from a dumpfile, pipe it into the Postgres command line tool `psql`.

```
psql dbname < dumpfile.sql
```

See also [the Postgres docs on backup and restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html).